# Is there a risk to reuse branch names?

Tags: git

I would like to work on a set of features in branch `features` and merge with `master` once a set of features is added. This will trigger a chnage in production.

I would then continue to work on the features, in the branch `features` (I do not want, if possible, to open a new branche for each feature of the planned features set).

Is there a specific risk to do so, **from git's perspective** ?

I know that there are ["best practices" for branch reuse](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284903/reusing-a-merged-branch-good-practice) but this development would be better orchestrated through a set of `work on branch features` -> `merge with master` -> `continue working on branch features` -> `merge with master` -> ...

I am the only developer, so [`master` does not change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32007121/903011) between the merges.

Comment: No, I don't see any relevant risk.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your third paragraph correctly, due to multiple "not"s and "but"s. You might want to rephrase that for better clarity.

Comment: And for your own judgement, you should consider that a branch is merely a pointer to a commit, it has relatively little effect what name that pointer has, except that there can't be two with the same name.

Comment: @mkrieger1: thanks for the feedback, I clarified the third paragraph, which indeed was over-engineered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

git itself won't be bothered by this.  Since you specified "from git's perspective", the short answer is "no".

There are two things to be aware of:

1) In the event you're preserving merge commits, the default commit messages reflect the branch name.  This is only a concern if seeing repeated "merge from feature" messages in the `master` history were to be a problem in your review workflow.

2) Since you specified "from git's perspective", I'm assuming you've already evaluated how your build tools or other software that interacts with git will respond.  As I can't evaluate what those (unspecified) tools will do, I am not endorsing this approach overall, but merely addressing the question of whether *git* cares one way or the other.